# Simple Linear Regression: Hat-Value $h_i$

Tags: regression, leverage, projection

I'm trying to finish proving that in simple-regression analysis, $h_i = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{(X_i - \bar{X})^2}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}(X_j - \bar{X})^2}$, where $h_i := h_{ii} = \sum_{j=1}^nh_{ij}^2$, the entries of the hat matrix $H$. I've done the following so far: for $x_i' = (1, X_i)$,  $$x_i'(X'X)^{-1}x_i = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & X_i \end{bmatrix}\left(\begin{bmatrix} n & \sum X_i\\ \sum X_i & \sum X_i^2 \end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ X_i\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & X_i \end{bmatrix}\frac{1}{n\sum X_i^2 - (\sum X_i)^2}\begin{bmatrix} \sum X_i^2 & -\sum X_i\\ -\sum X_i & n \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ X_i\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{n\sum X_i^2 - (\sum X_i)^2}\begin{bmatrix}0 & nX_i- \sum X_i^2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ X_i\end{bmatrix} = \frac{nX_i^2 - \sum X_i^2}{n\sum X_i^2 - (\sum X_i)^2}.$$ Now, I'm stuck... I do understand that $\frac{1}{n} \leq h_i \leq 1$, but am not sure where else to go from here. Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410854/proof-about-the-diagonal-element-of-the-hat-matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a misuse of indices. Inside the matrix, it should be $j$ because the summation index is different from $i$ of $x_i$ at the beginning. If we continue with $j$'s:
$$\begin{align}h_{ii}&=\frac{\sum_j X_j^2+nX_i^2-2\sum_j X_j}{n\sum_jX_j^2-(\sum_jX_j)^2}=\frac{\sum_j X_j^2+nX_i^2-2n\bar{X}+n\bar{X}^2-n\bar{X}^2}{n\sum_jX_j^2-n^2\bar{X}^2}\\&=\frac{\sum_jX_j^2-n\bar{X}^2}{n\sum_jX_j^2-n^2\bar{X}^2}+\frac{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{\sum_jX_j^2-n\bar{X}^2}\\&=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{\sum_j(X_j-\bar{X})^2}\end{align}$$

Comment: When I replace the $X_i$ with $X_j$ in the $(X'X)^{-1}$ matrix and do the multiplication, I end up getting $\sum_j X_j^2+nX_i^2-2X_i\sum_j X_j$ in the numerator for $h_{ii}$... am I understanding you correctly? Also, as for your first step above, I see that you add and subtract $n\bar{X}^2$ in the numerator, but what exactly are you doing to the denominator? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you should be getting that. For the denominator, I set $\sum_j X_j=n\bar{X}$, which is also done in the numerator.

Comment: I just have one more question--how do you simplify $\sum_jX_j^2-n\bar{X}^2$ to be $\sum_j(X_j-\bar{X})^2$? I've been grappling with the algebra for a while and I can't get it to work.

Comment: @Jake Open up the latter, and put $\sum_j X_j = n\bar{X}$.