# Generalization of Hat matrix diagonal elements $h_{ii}$ formula to multiple linear regression

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model

[In this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410854/proof-about-the-diagonal-element-of-the-hat-matrix), the OP states a formula for the hat matrix diagonal elements. I was wondering what would be a generalization of that formula to the multiple linear regression model.

Comment: The generalization is given at the very beginning of the answer in your referenced question: compute the diagonal elements of $X(X^\prime X)^{-}X^\prime.$

Answer (score 4):

The ith diagonal element of H, $h_{ii}=x_i^T(X^TX)^{-1}x_i$. Also,
The Mahalanobis distance between an individual point $xi$ and the mean of the data set is given by $$MD(x_i)=\sqrt{(x_i-\bar x)^T S^{-1}(x_i-\bar x)}$$
where $S$ is the sample variance–covariance matrix. For a model with an intercept, the leverage and the squared Mahalanobis distance of a point i are related as $$h_{ii}=1/n + \frac{1}{n-1}MD^2(x_i)$$
This last expression seems useful to me... Is there a context where we can be sure that $h_{ii}$ is of the order $O(1/n)$?

[See this link for more information, and from where this summary was taken from](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/hat-matrix)